# PowerShell - Read Certificate Issuer using public key

Tags: powershell, x509certificate, pki

Could someone guide me to read the issuer from public key?

I used to do this earlier using the below piece of code.

```
$Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import([Convert]::FromBase64String($KeyCred.key))
```

But its no more working.

Getting the below error.

```
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Import" with "1" argument(s):
"X509Certificate is immutable on this platform. Use the equivalent constructor instead."
```

I am using PowerShell 7. Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `read the issuer from public key` -- can you elaborate? What is stored in `$KeyCred.key`?

Comment: Hello Crypt32, $keycred.key has the key. I am pulling the key using a graphapi call to list app applications. And trying to pick up the azure ad apps which has a certificate configured.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?`$select=id,appId,createdDateTime,displayName,passwordCredentials,keyCredentials

Comment: Public key doesn't store the information you are looking for. This information is stored in certificate, not public key.

Comment: Thanks Crypt32, I am not an expert on PKI. But the trick I used to read the issuer manually is to append -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- at the beginning and -----END CERTIFICATE----- at the end of the key, ie $KeyCred.key and save it as .cer file, which will allow me to open the certificate. But this approach is not correct/or atleast lenghty. 

I am looking for automating a job to trigger alerts based on certificate expiry and needs to include the certificate issuer . And the piece of code which I posted was working fine with Powershell v5,  but not on V7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `$KeyCred.key` stores a base64-encoded string that represents the certificate (not public key), then you can use appropriate constructor like this:

```
$cert = [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new([Convert]::FromBase64String($KeyCred.key))
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a lot !

Comment: then you can accept my post as answer.

Comment: Sure, Just marked your comment as the answer!